# Issues in navigate one screen to another in Xcode 4.3.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, push

Currently i am working in simple iPhone app, Using Xcode 4.3.2 to create it, (Without using Storyboard) when i navigate one screen to another screen, error found Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1.address=0x7669739), Similarly i am using Story board to navigate one screen to another, its working fine. How to fix this issue, please help me

Thanks in Advance

I tried this (With out using StoryBoard)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title=@"Screen 1";

    UIButton *btn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 40);
    [btn setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(GoToMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

-(void)GoToMethod
{
    sample2 *s2 =[[sample2 alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:s2 animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the answer from the developer documentation or from searching stackoverflow

```
 sample2 *s2 = [[sample2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"sample2" bundle:nil]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:s2 animated:YES];
```

You need to mention the nib/xib name to load.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Now i tried this, but the error comes in  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString GoToMethod]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c82a20'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: i hope sample is a viewcontroller having an xib with it.

Comment: It seems the variable `btn`'s memory is leaking. Are you using `ARC`?

Comment: @Swati the `nib` isn't necessary - one might create the view programmatically

Comment: No i am not using ARC, then how to release btn memory, i tried to release [btn release]:

Comment: @Minu I thought so...Add `[btn release];` right after adding it to subview

Comment: Now i am create two ViewController without using xib, but not navigate to another screen, no errors comes it.

Comment: sorry i am using ARC in that application